# Doubly linked list wont work

Tags: c

When i run this, it doesn't report any errors, but nothing actually happens. It wont return the pointer to smallest element of the list, it just do nothing.

Make a function with pointer that points to the first element of the doubly 
linked list, that returns the pointer to the smallest element of the list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct list DLlist;

struct list{
    DLlist *next, *previous;
    int number;
};

DLlist *first = NULL;

int n=0;

DLlist* add(DLlist *end, int number){

DLlist* perm;
    perm = (DLlist *)malloc(sizeof(DLlist));
    perm->number = number;


if(first==NULL){
        first = perm;
        first->next = NULL;
        first->previous = NULL;
        end = perm;
}else{

    perm->next = NULL;
    end->next = perm;
    perm->previous = end;
    end = perm;
    return end;
    n++;

    }

}

DLlist* return_smallest(DLlist *first){
    DLlist *max;
    DLlist *current;
    first = max;
    current = first;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(current->number < max->number) max = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return max;
}

void main(){

    DLlist *end = NULL;

    int number;
    int choice;

do{
    printf("1-Add elements to list: \n"
           "2-Return a pointer to the smallest element in the list\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    scanf("%d",&number);

switch(choice){
    case 1: end = add(end, number);break;
    case 2: printf("%d",(return_smallest(first))->number);
    }

}while(choice == 1);
}
```

Comment: Provide a more useful problem description than "it doesn't do the job".

Comment: I made some changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `end` var is defined in `main()`, when you pass it to `add` you actually pass a copy of that pointer, so the change made inside the function isn't copied back to the variable in `main()` scope.

The usual approach in c is to pass its address (`DLlist**`) to the function and use it as a double pointer, so the update would be able to update the external variable.

You can also make `end` global like `first`, but that's a bad habit as it would prevent using multiple lists at the same time. Global variables are best avoided, but it would work as well.